# What is the correct way to build up a value from a stream?

Tags: node.js

I'm running an ffmpeg command in a child process; it converts a video file into a new format, emitting chunks of that new video to stdout as it goes, and I capture that with event handlers.

If I want to save the video as a file, I can create a writable stream for that file, and pipe the child process's stdout to it, that's fine. But now I want to generate screenshots from the videos, *not* to save as a file, but to create a base64 representation of that image in memory, then save it in a database. (I am aware that saving images in a database generally isn't recommended.)

I'm wondering now what the recommended way to do that is, to build up a value over time.

Right now, I've declared an array, `chunks`. Every time I get a new chunk of data from my ffmpeg process, I base64-encode it, and push it into `chunks`. When I get the `close` event from the stream, I call `join()` on that array, and that's my value.

This works fine, since my screenshots are 1 MB max. But is it a dumb thing to do? Is there something in the Node library, a structure like a stream or a buffer or a UIntArray, that's intended for this kind of purpose, rather than building up an array and then joining it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using array of Buffers, like this:

```
let chunks = [];
stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
stream.on('end', () => {
    let result = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('base64');
    // Do something with result
});
```

This is the most memory efficient way to do that. No extra structures. No memory duplications.